# "Input string was not in a correct format" when trying to print a List

Tags: c#

So I've been trying to do a program, which looked really simple at first, but I guess I must have underestimated it. The program is to receive 2 List with Console.ReadLine() and then merge them in a 3rd list, then List.Sort and print it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Array.Merge
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> numbers1 = input1.Split(" ").Select(int.Parse).ToList();
            List<int> numbers2 = input2.Split(" ").Select(int.Parse).ToList();
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            for (int a = 0; a < numbers1.Count; a++)
            {
                numbers.Add(numbers1[a]);
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < numbers2.Count; b++)
            {
                numbers.Add(numbers2[b]);
            }
            numbers.Sort();
            foreach(int number in numbers)
            {
                Console.Write(number + " ");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

when I submit my 2 lines of input, I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format" in the console.
This is the input I am using:

```
1 2 3 7 9 
2 4 5 7 8
```

This is what I should be receiving:

```
1 2 2 3 4 5 7 7 8 9
```

Comment: Note that if you have multiple spaces in sequence or a leading space or a trailing space in your input, then the result of `someInput.Split(" ")` will contain **empty strings**. And an empty string is not a string representation of any integer number, hence error. You can instruct the Split method to discard those empty strings by using `someInput.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and Bob should be your uncle...

Comment: FYI: Also note that in your second `for` loop regarding numbers2, you are accidentally using numbers1 instead...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace true, i copied it and forgot to change one of the values, thank you

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thank you, your solution fixes the problem, it's just that I've been mostly using string lists and I just copied the whole thing from another program. It would have taken me ages to figure out the " " is a string by itself and I'm trying to use it in an int List.

Comment: Another possible and robust solution is to loop directly over the string array resulting from the split and then use `if (int.TryParse(s, out int i)) {  numbers.Add(i); }`

Comment: @MartinKulev No, it's not that space `" "` you used as delimiter in the split will become part of the result. A string with a space `" "` is _not an empty string, because it contains one character (the space character). An empty string is a string with no characters, i.e., a string with a length of zero. So, why would there then be empty strings in the split result? Think of a string with two consecutive space characters, i.e. `<space><space>`. Using the space character as split delimiter, what is between these two split delimiters/space characters? An empty string - a string of length zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should always use `TryParse` methods if you handle user input
- Split can contain empty results, if you have multiple consecutive spaces and don't use [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0)

So this should work and is double safe:

```
List<int> numbers1 = input1.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(s => (IsValid: int.TryParse(s, out int Value), Value))
        .Where(x => x.IsValid)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
List<int> numbers2 = input2.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(s => (IsValid: int.TryParse(s, out int Value), Value))
       .Where(x => x.IsValid)
       .Select(x => x.Value)
       .ToList();

List<int> numbers = numbers1.Concat(numbers2).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

You can also create a (local) method to not repeat yourself:

```
List<int> GetValidInts(string s) => s?.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => (IsValid: int.TryParse(s, out int Value), Value))
    .Where(x => x.IsValid)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList() ?? new List<int>();

List<int> numbers1 = GetValidInts(input1);
List<int> numbers2 = GetValidInts(input1);
```